# How to avoid Edeliver deployment error: "vm.args: No such file or directory"?

Tags: deployment, elixir, phoenix-framework, edeliver, distillery

### Context

We are trying to use `edeliver` to deploy a "Hot Upgrade" of a Phoenix Web Application to a remote Virtual Machine instance.

Our aim is to build an "upgrade" version of the app each time so that the app can be "hot" upgraded in production without any down-time.

We have succeeded in doing this "hot upgrade" on a "Hello World" phoenix app: 
https://github.com/nelsonic/hello_world_edeliver which is *automatically* deployed from Travis-CI when the build passes. see: https://travis-ci.org/nelsonic/hello_world_edeliver/builds/259965752#L1752

So, in *theory* this technique should work for our "real" app.

### Attempting to Deploy a "Real" Phoenix App using Edeliver

Ran the following command (*to build the upgrade*):

```
mix edeliver build upgrade --auto-version=git-revision --from=$(git rev-parse HEAD~) --to=$(git rev-parse HEAD) --verbose
```

i.e. "build the upgrade from the previous git revision to the current one"

So far, so good. "*Release successfully built!*"

[image: edeliver-upgrade-build-successful]

### Error: `vm.args: No such file or directory`

When we attempt to *deploy* the upgrade:

```
mix edeliver deploy upgrade to production --version=1.0.3+86d55eb --verbose
```

[image: vm.args-no-such-file-or-directory]

```
cat: /home/hladmin/healthlocker/releases/1.0.3+86d55eb/vm.args: No such file or directory
```

> Note: we have a little bash script that reads the latest upgrade version available in `.deliver/releases` and deploys that see: [`version.sh`](https://github.com/nelsonic/hello_world_edeliver/blob/master/.deliver/version.sh)

### Question:

Is there a way to *ignore* the absence of the `vm.args` file and *continue* the deployment?

***Or*** if the file is *required* to complete the deployment, is there some documentation on how to create the file?

> Note: we have read the distillery "Runtime Configuration" docs: https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/blob/master/docs/Runtime%20Configuration.md and are sadly none-the-wiser ...

### Additional Info

#### Environment

- Localhost: Mac running Elixir 1.4.2
- Build Host: **Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS** running Elixir 1.4.5
- `mix.exs` file: https://github.com/healthlocker/healthlocker/blob/continuous-delivery/mix.exs
- `edeliver` version: `1.4.4`
- Build tool: `distillery` version: `1.4.0`
- Umbrella project: yes.

This question was also asked on: https://github.com/edeliver/edeliver/issues/234

Comment: You got answer under the topic under github.

Comment: vm.args is essential for the BEAM (The Erlang VM) to run for a release. It's generated by the exrm package when you run `mix release` and you should see it in the verbose logs as well - but not visible in your example, maybe due to the image cropping. Could you check if you see a line `==> Generating vm.args` in your output?

Comment: I believe you answer is in your question itself: "Note: we have a little bash script that reads the latest upgrade version available in .deliver/releases and deploys that see: version.sh". If the absence of the file can be causing an error, put a condition in your script in order to verify its existence.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, the `vm.args` file is necessary for BEAM to run the release. A default file is created by distillery during the release build process and should be located in [`releases/<version>/vm.args`](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/blob/master/docs/Runtime%20Configuration.md#vmargs). From your log output it looks like expected directory is being checked.

- Can you show us the contents of `/home/hladmin/healthlocker/releases/`?
- Can you confirm that the default `vm.args` file is being created when building the release and extracting it (outside of the upgrade process)?

You also asked:

> Or if the file is required to complete the deployment, is there some documentation on how to create the file?

If diagnosing the problem with the default `vm.args` file doesn't get you anywhere, you can also write your own file and configure distillery to use that file instead of the default. The details for this are in the [distillery configuration docs](https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/configuration.html#configuration). In short, 
add the `vm_args` setting to your distillery config, which should be at [`rel/config.exs`](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/blob/3c866828187ccb6041248d7257b5908f30ae8f9f/lib/mix/lib/releases/config/config.ex#L50)(relative to your project root), for example:

```
environment :prod do
  set vm_args: "<path>/vm.args"
  [...]
end
```